# Is there any approach to ensure a service is bound?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

According to the Android developer manual shows [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample), it seems to assume that once the client calls bindService(), eventually the service will be bound and the onServiceConnected() callback will be triggered.

However, in my application I received a crashed report due to the service is not bound after calling bindService and use this service object without null checking. It is a rare bug that cannot be repeated on my devices. Although I can fix this bug by adding null checking, that service is essential to my application and if it isn't connected, the app will not function properly. Therefore, I want to ensure the service connection being created in any case. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: bindService result is useless,  don't relay on it